# Dropzone does not work inside jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropzone.js

I am trying to use dropzone inside a jquery tab.

In the file that is being called by the tab I include `dropzone.min.js`, `dropzone.min.css`, `basic.min.css`.
I copied your code of the form.

I get the normal file input and not the drop zone option.
In firebug, I do see the `dropzone.min.js` is being called.

Trying the same code on a stand alone html file, everything is fine, besides the fact that I don't get the style you have.

Can this not work inside a tab?
Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Would you make fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to initialize it programatically instead of using a form:

http://www.dropzonejs.com/#create-dropzones-programmatically

Don't forget to set up an URL to an Action...

Regards,

Comment: NOT good reply, You should give answer more details or add example. Please do not reply as it. It takes more time for other when reading your answer.